# Entity Framework Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, excel, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am building an Excel import feature that allows the user to specify which columns map to which property of the object. Then using reflection, I create a new object, set the property values and insert the new object into the DbSet. However, some of the new objects may be duplicates and should update an existing record instead of being added to the DbSet as a new object.

The Excel sheet will not contain a column for the object's ID. So I'm wanting to add an Index for a combination of other fields (such as FirstName and LastName). I want to then pass in a list of objects to the stored procedure like passing in a table parameter; so I can select all the records from the database where the indexes match.

How can I pass in a list of objects into an Entity Framework stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DbSet is already a list objects to which you can add objects.
If you have a functional key that uniquely identifies each object, then you should be able to find and update it using LINQ.

Comment: This. The question sounds like an XY problem, asking how to work with an SPROC when it's probably simpler to just check for existing matches in LINQ itself and update instead of insert when necessary.

Comment: As our database grows, this will become more costly. I was told SQL Server can process this need more efficiently than in LINQ. No?

Comment: @Kris as I stated in my question, I won't have a column in the imported Excel file with an ID column. That's part of the problem.

Comment: You do not need a technical-id or primary key if you can identify a unique key in your data set by which you can uniquely point at each record. Use the unique key, probably a few columns, to insert and update.

Comment: After testing this, it was MUCH faster that I expected, even with large sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them through a comma separated list (string), as long as it's less than 8K characters. Then you can split them through this function. (The function would be used in the SP).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
@NameList Varchar(8000)

Select * from People 
where (FirstName+'-'+LastName) in dbo.Split(@NameList,',')
....
```

The function to split values base on a delimiter chararter

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @Input VARCHAR(8000),
    @Delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@Input) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@Input,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(@Input,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@Input)+1)-stpos) As Item
    FROM Split
)
```

Comment: I don't think this would be efficient. If I have 1000 rows I'm importing from Excel, I'd have to concat multiple values for each row then concat that contact'd value from each row into one gigantic string. Then SQL would have to split the values correctly for each row and then each column. While it would work, I'm looking for the most efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah, if that's the case, it's better to do it without SP's (just through Linq expressions),if it's possible. Otherwise you can insert those data into Temp tables and in the SP use those temp tables to do your query. But I'd suggest you do it through linq. Temp tables sound a bit hacky to me.